# method connect_ex((host,port)) for establishing a connection to a remote port. Why the double parentheses (())

Tags: python-3.x, security, network-programming

When using method connect_ex((host,port)) for establishing a connection to a remote port.
Why the double parentheses (())

Answer (score 2):

The argument to `connect` / `connect_ex` is generically just a single "address". The interpretation of the address differs according to the address family. This is explained in the `socket` documentation:
https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/socket.html?highlight=socket#socket-families

> The address format required by a particular socket object is automatically selected based on the address family specified when the socket object was created.

In the case of the `AF_INET` family, the address happens to consist of a `host` *and* a `port` hence there is a need to provide two pieces of information in one argument slot. The usual way to do that in python is to provide the two pieces as a `tuple`. The syntax for creating a tuple is to separate the two items with a tuple, but *within an argument list*, you must enclose the two items in an extra pair of parentheses.

That is:

```
connect_ex(host, port)   # WRONG
```

doesn't work because there would be two arguments, but the method expects only one. Either of these *does* work:

```
address = host, port     # Comma indicates a tuple
connect_ex(address)

connect_ex((host, port)) # () to distinguish as a tuple in the argument list
```